# VoiceOver in Chrome appears to read the opposite state of toggle buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on an AngularJS app and have created a directive for a toggle button. I'm using `role="button"` and `aria-pressed="true|false"` to make the element behave like a toggle button. When testing A11y with VoiceOver, the state of the button is spoken correctly when you first tab to it: something like "*label text* - selected - toggle button" if the toggle is checked, and "*label text* - toggle button" if it's unchecked.

The problem is: when you trigger the toggle, the voice feedback is pretty much the opposite of what I want. If it's an unchecked toggle and you trigger it to check it, the voice speaks "deselect *label text* toggle button". If it's checked and you trigger it to uncheck it, it speaks "select *label text* toggle button".

Also: toggling the button changes the label text, and when you trigger it, the label text that is spoken is the text that was there before toggling.

I can't help thinking this will be confusing to blind users - what the voice is saying about what has just happened is the opposite of what the user actually did.

My template looks like this:

```
<div aria-labelledby="{{lockId + 'Label'}}" aria-pressed="{{lockModel.locked}}" class="desktopLockToggle" ng-class="lockModel.locked ? 'locked' : ''" ng-model="lockModel.locked" role="button" ng-click="toggleMe($event)">
    <div class="slider">
    <span>{{toggleOnLabel}}</span>
    <span class="thumb"></span>
    <span>{{toggleOffLabel}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lockModel.locked" name="{{name}}" value="on" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive code looks like this:

```
.directive('desktopLockToggle', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
        return {
            require: '^form',
            restrict: 'E',
            template: *[see above]*,
            scope: {
                toggleOnLabel: '@',
                toggleOffLabel: '@',
                name: '@',
                lockId: '@',
                lockModel: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, form) {
                $scope.form = form;
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
                $scope.toggleMe = function(event) {
                    var $toggle = $(event.currentTarget);
                    var $checkBox = $toggle.find('input');
                    var toggledValue = $scope.lockModel.locked;

                    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
                        toggledValue = $scope.lockModel.locked = !$scope.lockModel.locked;
                    }
                    $toggle.attr('aria-pressed', toggledValue);
                    $checkBox.prop('checked', toggledValue);
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: 1. Do you have a sample URL where we can see this in action, perhaps a CodePen or JSBin, and 2. since VoiceOver pairs better with Safari, why are you using Chrome (perhaps user request)?

Comment: I've created a pen at https://codepen.io/stylecramper/pen/YVVBxL. And yes, it's a user request - from our accessibility compliance officer :)

Comment: Any accessibility gurus out there?

Comment: The toggle does not fire with either space or Enter when using NVDA / Firefox. I cannot properly test it, but I can tell you that if you throw `aria-labeledby="crdLockLabel"` on the `<desktop-lock-toggle>` then you may be in better shape. Get a keyboard-friendly one and I can test it for you.

Comment: The <div> nested inside <desktop-lock-toggle> has `aria-labelledby` pointing to the <label> element to its left. The <div> also has `tabindex="0"`. Are there other things I should be doing there?

Comment: I've made a change to the codepen - the <div> is now a <button>, should help.

Comment: This may be an Angular thing...if you have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility, there's an example of a <custom-checkbox> directive that displays the same behaviour I'm seeing with mine.

Comment: New discovery: it may be a Chrome thing. The <custom-checkbox> mentioned above works fine in Safari.

Comment: As I am traveling and on other work I have not been able to come back around to test since earlier. However, if you get the same issue in Chrome with the demo site, then it may be a bug in either Chrome or the Angular implementation. In either case, I think you can argue this as an edge case, file a bug against Angular, and move on.

Comment: Move on is pretty much what we've decided to do. Thanks for the input.